# Photoshop disable edge smoothing

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I have a selection in photoshop. But when i press the "DEL" key to delete the content from within the selection, it automatically smoothes the edges. I want that i deltes excatly without any smoothing. I am using Photoshop CS6.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, I have a hunch this might be much easier without needing to **use a different way**, when using the selection tool, look at the top tool bar, it will show an option called **Feather**, for a sharp cut from selection when hitting delete, this needs to be set to 0.

Anything other than 0 will smooth the edges depending on the input value.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

so i found the answer:
turns out when you use the selection->modify->border command to make a selection it will always smooth the edges automatically and i had to use a different way

Comment: What way did you use?